# Javascript window print footer only print page number

Tags: javascript, html, css

in javascript window.print function, how to remove the url in the page footer but still contains the page number? this is my result page.[image] I want the url to be gone but page number remain as the same, is it anyway i can achieve that? seems this code does not work.

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@page {
    size: landscape; margin:0 0 10mm 0 ;float: none !important;
}

a {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: do you think it is javascript issue?

Comment: I am still searching for the way. Is there any possible way with CSS or even with js?

Answer (score 1):

Easily you can achieve this by using CSS. For this answer, we are not using @page, which is a pure CSS answer, but work in FireFox 20+ versions. Here is the link to an example.

## The CSS is:

```
#content {
    display: table;
}

#pageFooter {
    display: table-footer-group;
}

#pageFooter:after {
    counter-increment: page;
    content: counter(page);
}
```

## And the HTML code is:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="pageFooter">Page </div>
  multi-page content here...
</div>
```

This way you can customize your page number by editing parameters to #pageFooter.

My example:

```
#pageFooter:after {
    counter-increment: page;
    content:"Page " counter(page);
    left: 0; 
    top: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    z-index: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;  
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);  
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);  
  }
```

Hope this trick will help you.

## For Total Page

You can use this

```
@page {
   @bottom-right {
    content: counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use the -moz vendor prefix? Each property you use is cross browser.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you kind response, that does the trick, but is it possible that i can get total pages as well? as like 1/total pages?

Comment: I updated my answer. Check that out. And don't forget to mark my answer as right.

Comment: Thank you for you update! but somehow it doesn't work, here is the example page, after click the print, it will still show the url  of the page, any way that can remove the url and show page as 1/total pages?http://jsfiddle.net/2tad9k8o/